# Differentiable function $x|x|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can i prove that the function $f(x) = x|x|$ is differentiable.

I stuck in this problem i have to take de cases when $x<0$ and $x>0$ and then this is the derivative ?, some help please.

Comment: Yes you do have to consider those cases, as well as $x = 0$. You haven't explained what you are stuck on.

Comment: $f^{'}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}2x&, x>0\\ -2x&, x<0\\ 0 &, x=0\end{array}\right.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that problem may occur at $x=0$ and hence we evaluate, $$f'(0)= \lim_{ h \to 0}\frac{h|h|}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}|h|=0$$ (since you are evaluating at 0)  . So f is differentiable at $0$. Hence $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a problem, it is on $0$.
So calculate
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
and prove that they are equal.

Comment: i understan i that true that the second derivative in x= o doesn't exist?

Comment: @Knight, Indeed yes :)

Answer (score 2):

If $x>0$ or $x<0$ you can write an obviously differentiable formula for $f$ that
is valid in a neighbourhood of $x$ (that does not contain zero).

If $x=0$, then note that $|f(h)-f(0)-0 \cdot h| = |h|^2$. If we let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $h$ such that $|h| < \epsilon$, we see that
$|f(h)-f(0)-0 \cdot h| \le \epsilon|h|$, and so
from the definition of derivative, we see that $f'(0) = 0$.